# Routing without controller and action in the url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do I configure ASP.NET MVC 3 routing so it doesn’t require the controller and action in the url?

I have this to display the details for item “abc123”, configured with the default routing-settings:

```
mysite.com/Home/Details/abc123
```

The value "abc123" is a unique value which the Home controller uses to look up the correct item in a database.

But I would prefer to have these ultra-short urls instead:

```
mysite.com/abc123
```

The site will also have very few additional controllers, such as “About” and “Contact”. I assume I would have to configure those specifically as well, so the default controller doesn’t start looking for details for an item with ID “About” or “Contact”. How do I do that?

UPDATE:

Here's what my routes ended up looking like:

```
routes.MapRoute("About", "About", New With {.controller = "About", .action = "Index"})
routes.MapRoute("ID", "{id}", New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Details"})
routes.MapRoute("Default", "", New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"})
```

:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Site"
              , "Site/{controller}/{action}"
                , new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});

routes.MapRoute("Id"
              , "{id}"
                , new { controller = "Home", action = "Details"});
```

The first route should ensure that you can have /Site/About and /Site/Contact mapped to AboutController and ContactController respectively. It is important that this gets mapped first.

The second route will make sure that /abc123 gets mapped to the details action with id "abc123"

Comment: It's working! Do you know how I configure it to call a different action if no ID is present, i.e. just "mysite.com/"?

Comment: Great! :) I was going to say that you can solve it by adding one more default route like this routes.MapRoute("Default", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}); in the top. I would suggest you write some tests for your routing as well because it's easy to break them by changing something somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
routes.MapRoute("abc123"
              , "Home/Details/{name}"
                , new { controller = "Home", action = "Detail", name = ""});
```

and your action looks like:

```
public ActionResult Detail(string name)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: The value "abc123" is a unique identifier, which the default controller will use to look up the item in a database. I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think your pattern doesn't match the url "mysite.com/abc123" and therefore the route is not used. Perhaps your pattern should be "{name}" and then the defaults fill out the missing aspects?

Comment: @Jacob the "abc123" is merely the name of the route and has no further effect towards its functionality, the first string could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("abc123", "abc123", new { controller = "Home", action = "Details"});
```

I'm using MVC3 and it works for me.